# How to create svg file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, svg

I'm making a web page with JSP and Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).

When working with VSCode, I simply create an empty svg file and paste the source code of image into it.

I expected Eclipse to behave as VSCode, however, it seems there is no svg file creating option for Eclipse.

**Is an additional library essential to create svg file in Eclipse?**

If not, I will be very much appreciated with your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on any folder or package in the file explorer or package explorer, or any file/class in the file explorer or package explorer, pick *new*, and then pick *File*. This will make a file in selected directory (/ directory that contains the source files of the selected package / same dir as the file/class you selected). Just enter the file name, and include the `.svg` file extension.

Eclipse will just treat it as a plain text file.

> paste the source code of image into it.

If you mean, paste SVG in there - that works. If you mean: paste a PNG in there and expect the editor to create a bunch of scaffolding to have a PNG in an SVG, no that won't work, and that seems bizarre to want this, that is just getting you the worst aspects of PNG and the worst aspects of SVG.

I'm not aware of any SVG-specific plugins for eclipse.